# Getting ? while bcp out data from sybase with umlaut character(¬)

Tags: sybase, bcp

I am trying to bcp out data from Sybase to .bcp file. while doing bcp (¬) character alone getting displayed as '?'. Any suggestion?

Comment: seems to be encoding issue

Comment: Hi, Don't forget to upvote/accept helpful answers.  :?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your `bcp` utility is not using the same charset as your database or the terminal.  You may have to play with the `bcp` options that will to force the output to match what you need.

Here are the flags:

```
[-a display_charset]
[-z language]
[-J client_charset]
```

[SAP/Sybase ASE Utility Guide: bcp](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/X14951.htm)

> **-a display_charset**
>
> allows you to run bcp from a terminal where the character set differs from that of the machine on which bcp is running. Use -a in
> conjunction with -J to specify the character set translation file
> (.xlt file) required for the conversion. Use -a without -J only if the
> client character set is the same as the default character set.
>
> **-z language**
>
> is the official name of an alternate language the server uses to display bcp prompts and messages. Without the -z flag, bcp uses the
> server’s default language.
>
> You can add languages to an Adaptive Server during installation or afterwards, using either the langinstall utility (or langinst in
> Windows) or the sp_addlanguage stored procedure.
>
> **-J client_charset**
>
> specifies the character set to use on the client. bcp uses a filter to convert input between client_charset and the Adaptive Server
> character set.
>
> -J client_charset requests that Adaptive Server convert to and from client_charset, the character set used on the client.
>
> -J with no argument sets character set conversion to NULL. No conversion takes place. Use this if the client and server use the same
> character set.
>
> Omitting -J sets the character set to a default for the platform, which may not necessarily be the character set that the client is
> using.

For more information about character sets and associated flags, see the [System Administration Guide](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1550/html/sag1/X60641.htm).

Comment: This is a very good article about character sets if you want background:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html